# Create custom attribute in catalog category display setting

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

We are working to add custom attribute in catalog category display setting. but it not working in my server

could you please check code and let us now where i made mistakes.

code/Tendersoftware/Categoryattr/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Mod ule/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Tendersoftware_Categoryattr" setup_version="1.0.6">

   </module></config>

code\Tendersoftware\Categoryattr\Setup\InstallData.php
namespace Tendersoftware\Categoryattr\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\{
ModuleContextInterface,
ModuleDataSetupInterface,
InstallDataInterface
};

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
private $eavSetupFactory;

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'proteamcat', [
        'type'     => 'int',
        'label'    => 'Pro team category design',
        'input'    => 'boolean',
        'source'   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
        'visible'  => true,
        'default'  => '0',
        'required' => false,
        'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'group'    => 'Display Settings',
    ]);
}
```

}

code\Tendersoftware\Categoryattr\View\adminhtml\ui_component\category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="display_settings">
    <field name="proteamcat">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Pro team category design</item>
                <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                </item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

code\Tendersoftware\Categoryattr\registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Tendersoftware_Categoryattr',
__DIR__
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following sample module code to add custom category attribute.

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_Custom',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_Custom" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/Setup/InstallData.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Anshu\Custom\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config as EavConfig;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var EavConfig
     */
    private $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, EavConfig $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        //Adding category attribute
        $catAttributeCode = 'cat_custom';

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(CategoryAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, $catAttributeCode, [
            'label' => 'My Custom Category Attribute',
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'unique' => 1,
        ]);

        //Adding this new attribute to default attribute group of default attribute set
        $catSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(CategoryAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE);
        $catGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(CategoryAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, $catSetId);
        $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(CategoryAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, $catSetId, $catGroupId, $catAttributeCode);

    }
}
```

Change the code according to your requirement.